# wygwam upload assets set keyword

Tags: assets, wygwam

Izzit possible to input keyword right on the wygwam uploader. Now when I right click it only show "view file" I wish there is a way that I can have "edit" so our editor can input some keywords for that particular image they upload for their article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin - I am sorry that I missed this!  Unfortunately this is not currently possible, you'd need to edit the Metadata from an Assets field or the Assets CP.